# Testing a specific struct data member with std::equal_to, etc

Tags: c++, c++11, std

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

struct blah {
    int member;
};

int main (int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    blah a = { 1 };
    auto are_same = std::bind(
            std::equal_to<blah>(),
            a,
            std::mem_fn(&blah::member)   // Obviously not a function, but I tried.
        );

    std::vector<blah> blahs = { {0}, {1}, {2} };
    return static_cast<int>(std::any_of(blahs.begin(), blahs.end(), are_same));
}
```

This program fails to compile (GCC 4.4):

```
error: no match for call to ‘(std::equal_to<blah>) (blah&, std::_Mem_fn<int blah::*>&)’
```

**Aside from coding the loop myself, what's the correct way to check for equivalence based on a data member?**

Comment: Do you want to check generally for equality of `blah`s or do you just want to check a single member for equality? If the former, implement `operator==` for the `struct`.

Comment: I'm looking to examine specific data members.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're already using C++11, why not use a lambda?

```
int main (int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    blah a = { 1 };
    auto are_same = [=](blah const& b) -> bool {
        return a.member == b.member;
    };

    std::vector<blah> blahs = { {0}, {1}, {2} };
    return static_cast<int>(std::any_of(blahs.begin(), blahs.end(), are_same));
}
```

If you can't use lambdas, you can use bind to do function composition:

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
auto are_same = std::bind(
  std::equal_to<int>(),
  std::bind(&blah::member, _1),
  std::bind(&blah::member, a)
);
```

Comment: This is of course correct. Unfortunately, I'm targeting gcc4.4 for the short term future.

Comment: @AndresJaanTack Added the form using bind composition, it works with GCC 4.6.1, don't know aobut 4.4 as I don't have it at hand.

Comment: Seems then that I am yet limited by my compiler. :(

Answer (score 2):

> Aside from coding the loop myself, what's the correct way to check for equivalence based on a data member?

Normal way of checking for equivalence is to implement the `operator==`. In your case, I guess it would look like this :

```
bool operator==( const blah & lho, const blah & rho )
{
  return ( lho.member == rho.member );
}
```

Comment: Eh, this is true for like 60% of cases, but for generated code and "look for an element with this attribute" searches, as the above, sadly inapplicable.